# Is it possible to define a default generic type?

Tags: .net, generics

```
public class StuffDoer<T>
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I want that this is always of type string, so instead of doing this:

```
StuffDoer<string> stuffer = new StuffDoer<string>();
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
StuffDoer stuffer = new StuffDoer();
```

and if I need a StuffDoer of type int, just define that with generics.

```
StuffDoer<int> stuffer = new StuffDoer<int>();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using subclasses where there's no real specialization going on, I would suggest using a separate static "factory" class:

```
public static class StuffDoer
{
    public static StuffDoer<string> Create()
    {
        return new StuffDoer<string>();
    }

    public static StuffDoer<T> Create<T>()
    {
        return new StuffDoer<T>();
    }


    public static StuffDoer<T> Create<T>(T item)
    {
        StuffDoer<T> ret = new StuffDoer<T>();
        ret.Add(item); // Or whatever
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The last method lets you use type inference as well:

```
StuffDoer<int> doer = StuffDoer.Create(10);
```

This doesn't let you write `new StuffDoer()` admittedly - but I think it's a cleaner solution. Creating a non-generic derived class just as a sort of "type alias" feels like an abuse of inheritance to me.

Comment: the approach of inheritance indeed looks good, but this might indeed be better because it is more intended to hide instead of real inheritance

Answer (score 3):

You can just setup a plain `StuffDoer` class that inherits from `StuffDoer<T>`:

```
public class StuffDoer : StuffDoer<string>
{
    // ...
}

public class StuffDoer<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think mine is a lot more attractive!

Answer (score 3):

```
public class StuffDoer<T>
{
    // do stuff
}

public class StuffDoer : StuffDoer<string>
{
    // do stuff
}
```